# Define Location of JavaScript on Page within Canvas

Tags: pixi.js

I have a little Pixi.js JavaScript I would like to have placed on a specific place on a WordPress page. Right now, it is displaying at the bottom of the page, despite my defining that it should be placed within a canvas.

(It seems to render correctly here, but not on my WordPress site)

Please let me know where I went wrong.

```js
       
        
        let app = new PIXI.Application({width:683, height:455, antialias:true, view:myCanvas});
        document.body.appendChild(app.view);
           
        let img = new PIXI.Sprite.from("https://devlucidpix.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/4-illumination-tree-lights-morton-arboretum.jpg");
        img.width = 683;
        img.height =455;
        app.stage.addChild(img);    
            
        depthMap = new PIXI.Sprite.from("https://devlucidpix.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/4-illumination-tree-lights-morton-arboretum_depth.jpg");
        depthMap.width = 683;
        depthMap.height = 455;
        app.stage.addChild(depthMap);
        displacementFilter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(depthMap);
        app.stage.filters = [displacementFilter];
        
        window.onmousemove = function(e) {
        displacementFilter.scale.x = (window.innerWidth / 2 - e.clientX) /20;
        displacementFilter.scale.y = (window.innerHeight / 2 - e.clientY) /20;
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.min.js"></script>
        Some pre-image text goes here <br /><br />        
        
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="683" height="455" style="border:8px solid #076e21; width:683; height:455;">
        <img src="https://devlucidpix.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/4-illumination-tree-lights-morton-arboretum.jpg" width="683" height="455" alt=""/>
        </canvas>
        
         <br /><br />
        And here's some text after it.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Application.html

```
view    HTMLCanvasElement       optional    
The canvas to use as a view, optional.
```

in your code there is :

```
let app = new PIXI.Application({width:683, height:455, antialias:true, view:myCanvas});
```

so the question is: what is the variable `myCanvas` here? Where and how it was initialized?
As you see in the docs it should be `HTMLCanvasElement`

Comment: The HTML code has a canvas tag with an id of myCanvas, which corresponds with the pixi.application's view.

Comment: @Fullerton see my example : https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/Ci0UBCqcpTnUGGe_gGKQw - as you see it works if you pass right html element to "view" option when initializing PIXI.Application. Can you make "console.log(myCanvas)" before line where you initialize PIXI.Application and paste here the output?

Answer (score 0):

- The fact that your pixijs canvas was displayed at all means your code is working (hell, no idea how because @domis86 is right, but it's JavaScript, so who cares?)
- I was able to reproduce both behaviors: expected - on a local PHP server and the actual one - on my site running on WordPress. Basically using your code snippets.
- As it's maybe due to how WordPress generates its elements, I suggest you to:

  1. Instead of `<canvas>` create some `<div>` element with `id` you wanted to use:

     `<div id="myCanvas" width="683" height="455"... </div>`
  2. Let pixiJS put the canvas with its view inside using `document`, but with explicitly located of the element you created above:

     ```
     let app = new PIXI.Application({width:683, height:455, antialias:true });

     document.getElementById("myCanvas").appendChild(app.view);
     ```